# Is there a more CoffeeScripty way to do this?

Tags: coffeescript, namespaces, default

Here's some code I have:

```
window.MyNamespace ?= {}
window.MyNamespace.Subnamespace ?= {}
window.MyNamespace.Subnamespace.Subsubnamespace ?= {}
```

Is there a way to clean this up in a CoffeeScripty way?

Answer (score 2):

The only alternative I can think of, is to use this somewhat obscure syntax:
`((window.MyNamespace ?= {}).Subnamespace ?= {}).Subsubnamespace ?= {}`

See also [this issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/1394) which proposes a way to create an object property if it doesn't exist.